# Have a complicated query to insert some data that is not entering my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic form I want Users to enter data from then insert that information into my database. My query is a little complicated and when I attempt to execute the query I am getting back an error message. Looking for a solution to help solve this problem.

Here is a little bit of code to give you an idea of what my problem looks like. I have a form with a submit button that sends the user input fields to `saveSale.php` and that is where my insert query is.

In my `saveSale` file I tried checking the result to find out if the query was a success.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO lead_log (";
$query .= "salesperson_id, fname, lname, address, city, state, 
            zip, source, commercial, paperwork_submitted, claim_submitted, 
            commission_earned, date_proposal, date_install, date_sold, 
            date_followup, status, sale_price, amount_quoted, ac, hp, 
            furnace, ah, boiler, generator, minisplit1, minisplit2, 
            minisplit3, minisplit4, accessories1, accessories2, 
            accessories3, accessories4, accessories5, accessories6, 
            accessories7, comments, followup";

$query .= " ) VALUES (";

$query .= "' . $currentUser->id ', '{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$address}, '{$city}, '{$state}', '{$zip}', ";

$query .= "' {$_POST['source']}', '{$_POST['commercial']}', '{$_POST['paperwork_submitted']}','{$_POST['claim_submitted']}', '{$commission_earned}', ";

$query .= "'" .convertDate($_POST['date_proposal']). "'," .convertDate($_POST['date_install'])."',";

$query .= "'".convertDate($_POST['date_sold'])."'," .convertDate($_POST['date_followup'])."',";

$query .= " '{$_POST['status']}', '{$salePrice}', '{$amount_quoted}', '{$_POST['AC']}', '{$_POST['HP']}', '{$_POST['furnace']}',
          '{$_POST['AH']}', '{$_POST['boiler']}', '{$_POST['generator']}', '{$_POST['minisplit1']}', '{$_POST['minisplit2']}',
          '{$_POST['minisplit3']}', '{$_POST['minisplit4']}', '{$_POST['accessories1']}', '{$_POST['accessories2']}', '{$_POST['accessories3']}',
          '{$_POST['accessories4']}', '{$_POST['accessories5']}', '{$_POST['accessories6']}', '{$_POST['accessories7']}', '{$comments}', '{$followup}' " ;

$query .= ")";
$result = $con->query($query);
if ($result) {
    redirect_to("index.php");
    echo "Insert Successful";
} else {
    echo "Insert Failure";
}
```

Form

```
 <form action="saveSale.php" method="post" name='form' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" class='buttonClass defaultButton'/>
```

`Query Result`

```
INSERT INTO lead_log (salesperson_id, fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, source, commercial, paperwork_submitted, claim_submitted, commission_earned, date_proposal, date_install, date_sold, date_followup, status, sale_price, amount_quoted, ac, hp, furnace, ah, boiler, generator, minisplit1, minisplit2, minisplit3, minisplit4, accessories1, accessories2, accessories3, accessories4, accessories5, accessories6, accessories7, comments, followup ) VALUES (' . 1 ', 'Montrell', 'Sampson', ', ', '', '', ' ', 'n', '','', '0', '-03-21',0000-01-01','0000-01-01',0000-01-01', 'Sold', '13107.00', '13107.00', '73', '14', '218', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', '48', 'null', '45', '45', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'none', '' )
```

[This is an image with my error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l32V5.png)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: *"I am getting back an error message"* What is it?

Comment: Please post error message here.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you told us what the error message you got actually was.

Comment: Could you provide final `$query` value before `mysqli_query` call?

Comment: Obviously you will get error messages, if you didn't getting what the error message is than you can share screenshot too.

Comment: I'm getting an error message in the if statement because the query failed.

Comment: Use this statement to show what error you got in the query, and the sql statement `else{ echo "Insert Failure. Error: ".mysqli_error().". Query: <br /> <pre>$query</pre>";}`. This way we know how best to assist you

Comment: Thank you for the help I'm new at using StackOverFlow and it takes time to get an understanding of the community.

Comment: Insert Failure. Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','0000-01-01',0000-01-01', 'Sold', '13107.00', '13107.00', '73', '14', '218', ' at line 1. Query:

Comment: `," .convertDate($_POST['date_followup'])."'` <- missing a single quote around that. Note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah I know I have to redesign my page to prevent these injections just want to figure out my query first.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO lead_log (salesperson_id, fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, source, commercial, paperwork_submitted, claim_submitted, commission_earned, date_proposal, date_install, date_sold, date_followup, status, sale_price, amount_quoted, ac, hp, furnace, ah, boiler, generator, minisplit1, minisplit2, minisplit3, minisplit4, accessories1, accessories2, accessories3, accessories4, accessories5, accessories6, accessories7, comments, followup ) VALUES (' . 1 ', 'Montrell', 'Sampson', ', ', '', '', ' ', 'n', '','', '0', '-03-21',0000-01-01','0000-01-01',0000-01-01', 'Sold', '13107.00', '13107.00', '73', '14', '218', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', '48', 'null', '45', '45', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'none', '' )
```

There seem to be 2 quotation marks missing it should probably look like something like this

```
INSERT INTO lead_log (salesperson_id, fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, source, commercial, paperwork_submitted, claim_submitted, commission_earned, date_proposal, date_install, date_sold, date_followup, status, sale_price, amount_quoted, ac, hp, furnace, ah, boiler, generator, minisplit1, minisplit2, minisplit3, minisplit4, accessories1, accessories2, accessories3, accessories4, accessories5, accessories6, accessories7, comments, followup ) VALUES (' . 1 ', 'Montrell', 'Sampson', ', ', '', '', ' ', 'n', '','', '0', '-03-21','0000-01-01','0000-01-01','0000-01-01', 'Sold', '13107.00', '13107.00', '73', '14', '218', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', '48', 'null', '45', '45', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'none', '' )
```

So try changing your code from :

```
$query .= "'" .convertDate($_POST['date_proposal']). "'," .convertDate($_POST['date_install'])."',";

$query .= "'".convertDate($_POST['date_sold'])."'," .convertDate($_POST['date_followup'])."',";
```

to :

```
$query .= "'" .convertDate($_POST['date_proposal']). "','" .convertDate($_POST['date_install'])."',";

$query .= "'".convertDate($_POST['date_sold'])."','" .convertDate($_POST['date_followup'])."',";
```

I would highly suggest to try to properly format your code as @RiggsFolly suggested, it makes it easier to read and edit later on.

Also, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection so watch out for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help